# Graph in which no cycle has two crossing chords

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph which does not contain a simple cycle $v_1\ldots v_k$ and two "crossing" chords $v_iv_j$ and $v_pv_q$, $i<p<j<q$. An example of such graph is a triangulation of the convex polygon. Is it true that the number of edges in $G$ does not exceed $2n-3$, where $n$ denotes the number of vertices?

Comment: Isn't such a graph automatically outerplanar?

Comment: @MartinRubey it may be even not planar (take a subdivision of $K_5$)

Comment: Cool, thanks.  $K_{2,3}$ is another example.

Comment: If the graph is Hamiltonian and has this property, then it is outerplanar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thomassen and Toft [[JCTB 31(2):199-224, 1981](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0095-8956(81)80025-1)] showed that any graph with minimum degree at least 3 contains a cycle with two crossing chords from neighbouring vertices on the cycle. The $2n-3$ upper bound follows by induction on $n$, since we may delete a vertex of degree at most $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $n=2k+2$ is even. Let $G$ be the graph obtained from a matching $v_1w_1,\dots,v_kw_k$ by adding two vertices $x$ and $y$ both adjacent to all of
$v_1,w_1,\dots,v_k,w_k$. So $G$ has $n$ vertices and $5k=\frac{5}{2}(n-2)$ edges. Consider a cycle $C$ in $G$. If $|C|=3$ then $C$ has no chords. Otherwise $|C|=4$ and both $x$ and $y$ are in $C$. If $C=(x,v_i,y,w_i)$ for some $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$,  then $C$ has only one chord (namely $v_iw_i$). Otherwise $C$ has no chords. So $G$ satisfies a stronger property (every cycle has at most one chord).

Comment: Cycles $(x, v_i, w_i, y, v_j, w_j)$ have crossing chords $xw_i$ and $y v_i$.

Comment: Good point. My example says nothing!